# Club JSON Object on unique key in javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to create a neater JSON object by clubbing multiple objects with same IDs. 
Here's what I've tried:
 1. Store the ID of the first object to match subsequent IDs.
 2. Iterate over the array and check for similar IDs, If returns a match, push names as object in another array else push into a new object with stored names as a property.
 3. Empty names.

There were a lot of conditions to check if the object is the last element of the array and all that. I am just looking for an optimized way to achieve this. Considering the specific nature of the problem, I haven't been able to find the exact similar problem in SO.

I have a JSON Object like:

```
[
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'John'
},
{
    id: 1,
    name: 'Jack'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Drake'
},
{
    id: 2,
    name: 'Joey'
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Justin'
},
{
    id: 3,
    name: 'Rob'
}
]
```

I'd like to club together objects with similar ids, somewhat like this:

```
[{
    id: 1,
    names: [{
        name: 'John'
    },
    {
        name: 'Jack'
    }]
},
{
    id: 2,
    names: [{
        name: 'Drake'
    },
    {
        name: 'Joey'
    }]
},
{
    id: 3,
    names: [{
        name: 'Justin'
    },
    {
        name: 'Rob'
    }]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`Array#forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and an object for the hashes.

```js
var data = [{ id: 1, name: 'John' }, { id: 1, name: 'Jack' }, { id: 2, name: 'Drake' }, { id: 2, name: 'Joey' }, { id: 3, name: 'Justin' }, { id: 3, name: 'Rob' }],
    grouped = [];

data.forEach(function (a) {
    if (!this[a.id]) {
        this[a.id] = { id: a.id, names: [] };
        grouped.push(this[a.id]);
    }
    this[a.id].names.push({ name: a.name });
}, Object.create(null));

console.log(grouped);
```

Comment: That's really slick using the `this` arg for the `forEach` call to store the index

Comment: Thanks Nina, that was helpful.
Just one question though, what exactly is the null object doing here?

Comment: the part `Object.create(null)` creates a really empty object, without prototypes, like `toString`. this object is used as `this` object inside of the callback ad hash table for the reference to `id`.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method with an index reference object.

```js
var data = [{  id: 1,  name: 'John'}, {  id: 1,  name: 'Jack'}, {  id: 2,  name: 'Drake'}, {  id: 2,  name: 'Joey'}, {  id: 3,  name: 'Justin'}, {  id: 3,  name: 'Rob'}];

// object for index reference
var ind = {};

// iteraate over array
var res = data.reduce(function(arr, obj) {
  // check index defined already
  if (ind.hasOwnProperty(obj.id)) {
    // if defined then push the name value
    arr[ind[obj.id]].names.push({name: obj.name});
  } else {
    // else push a new object in prefered format
    arr.push({ id: obj.id, names: [{ name: obj.name }] });
    // define the index in reference object
    ind[obj.id] = arr.length - 1;
  }
  // return the updated array
  return arr;
  // set initial value as epty array
}, []);

console.log(res);
```